# How to prove $\sqrt{2a+3bc}+\sqrt{2b+3ca}+\sqrt{2c+3ab}\ge 3\sqrt{5}$?

Tags: inequality, radicals

> If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3$ then prove that: $$\sqrt{2a+3bc}+\sqrt{2b+3ca}+\sqrt{2c+3ab}\ge 3\sqrt{5}.$$

I've tried to use AM-GM and Holder without success.

Indeed, by AM-GM for three numbers $$\sqrt{2a+3bc}+\sqrt{2b+3ca}+\sqrt{2c+3ab}\ge 3\sqrt[6]{(2a+3bc)(2b+3ca)(2c+3ab)}$$ and we need to prove $$(2a+3bc)(2b+3ca)(2c+3ab)\ge 125$$
I check it is wrong when $a=b=\sqrt{3}; c=0.$

Also by Holder, $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2a+3bc}\right)^2\cdot \sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c+xa)^3}{2a+3bc}\ge (x+2)^3(a+b+c)^3$$
I was stuck to find $x$ satisfying $$(x+2)^3(a+b+c)^3\ge 45\cdot \sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c+xa)^3}{2a+3bc}$$ since equality occurs when $a=b=c=1.$

I think there is a better Holder using but I've not found it so far.

---

**Update $1:$** I tried AM-GM $$\sqrt{2a+3bc}=\frac{2a+3bc}{\sqrt{2a+3bc}}\ge \frac{2(2a+3bc)}{\dfrac{2a+3bc}{a+tbc}+a+tbc}$$but it's not smooth.

Comment: I think you can simplify your issue by getting rid of coefficients $2$ and $3$ ; just set $a'=a/k,b'=b/k,c'=c/k$ for a certain constant $k$ such that $2k=3k^2 \iff k=\sqrt{2/3}$. Your inequality will become $\sqrt{a'+b'c'}+\sqrt{b'+c'a'}+\sqrt{c'+a'b'} \ge ...$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think so.

Comment: consider "isolated fudging" https://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/wc08/ineq.pdf

Comment: @vallev It is hard for me. Is there a simple idea?

Comment: A (maybe too) simple idea is to un-symmetrize your issue by expressing $c=(3-ab)/(a+b)$ ; plugging it into your inequality, you get an expression in only two variables...

Comment: @TATA box What do you mean by "I don't think so" ?

Comment: What does happen to the given condition when you replace it?

Comment: @TATA box : it becomes $a'b'+b'c'+c'a'=2$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I used AM-GM and got that $\sqrt{2a+3bc} + \sqrt{2b+3ca} + \sqrt{2c+3ab} \geq 3\sqrt{2} (6 a b c)^{1/4}$ then I tried to use rearrangement inequality and $ab+bc+ca=3$ but nothing happened :((

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Yes, it seems not easy at all.

Comment: Where is the problem come from?

Answer (score 2):

**Proof.**

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sqrt{\frac{2a + 3bc}{5}} + \sqrt{\frac{2b + 3ca}{5}} + \sqrt{\frac{2c + 3ab}{5}}  \ge 3. \tag{1}$$

By AM-GM, we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{2a + 3bc}{5}} = \frac{12(2a + 3bc)}{2\sqrt{180(2a + 3bc)}}
\ge \frac{12(2a + 3bc)}{\frac{180(2a + 3bc)}{25 + 5bc} + (25 + 5bc)}. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{12(2a + 3bc)}{\frac{180(2a + 3bc)}{25 + 5bc} + (25 + 5bc)} \ge 3. \tag{3}$$

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 3, r = abc$. We have
$$p \ge 3, \quad 0 \le r \le 1, \quad r \ge \frac{12p - p^3}{9}. \tag{4}$$
(*Note*: $r \ge \frac{12p - p^3}{9}$ follows from the degree three Schur inequality $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$.)

(3) is equivalently written as
$$775r^4 + m_3 r^3 + m_2 r^2 + m_1 r + m_0 \ge 0 \tag{5}$$
where
\begin{align*}
 m_3 &= 200p^2 + 16510p + 3360, \\
 m_2 &= 7840p^3 + 6115p^2 - 4720p + 672952, \\
 m_1 &= 788768p^2 - 1388944p - 3990360, \\
 m_0 &= 16000p + 29308.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that (5) is true for all $p, r$ satisfying (4).

Since $m_3, m_2, m_0 \ge 0$, we only need to prove the case that $m_1 < 0$ which implies $p < 2\sqrt{3}$. Thus, $r \ge \frac{12p - p^3}{9} \ge 0$. Let $r_1 := \frac{12p - p^3}{9}$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &775r^4 + m_3 r^3 + m_2 r^2 + m_1 r + m_0\\
 \ge{}& 775r_1^4 + m_3 r_1^3 + m_2 r_1^2 + m_1 + m_0 \\
 ={}& \frac{1}{6561}(p - 3)g(p)\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 g(p) &:= 775\,{p}^{11}+525\,{p}^{10}-184215\,{p}^{9}+116955\,{p}^{8}+6865020\,{
  p}^{7}\\
 &\qquad +5282820\,{p}^{6}-11077668\,{p}^{5}+57435156\,{p}^{4}-791753940
 \,{p}^{3}\\
 &\qquad -2378061180\,{p}^{2}+5890235436\,p+8662820724.
\end{align*}

We are done.